# proof writing (sequences)

Tags: real-analysis

Fix $n \in N$. Prove that if the sequence {$a_{k}$} is convergent with limit $l, l \neq 0$ and if $a^{1/n}_{k}$ is defined for all $ k \in N$, then {$a^{1/n}_{k}$} is convergent with limit $l^{1/n}$

$\it{Hint}$ : use the identity

$a^q-b^q = (a-b)(a^{q-1}+a^{q-2}b+a^{q-3}b^2+\dots +b^{q-1})$ with suitable choice for a,b and q

Can I prove this by substituting $a^q =${$a^{1/n}_{k}$}, $b^q = l^{1/n}, a=$ {$a_{k}$} and $b=l$? Since that would prove $a^q-b^q$ is null. Will the power rule be useful here?

Comment: What do you mean by power rule?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to prove that ${a_k^{1/n}}$ is Cauchy based on the fact that ${a_k}$ is Cauchy (why is $a_k$ cauchy?).

Let $\epsilon > 0$ then we need to find an index $I$ such that for any $l,k > I,\ $ 
$a_l^{1/n} - a_k^{1/n} < \epsilon$. Since ${a_k}$ is cauchy therefore we can always find some index $J$ so that $a_l - a_k < \mu\ \ \forall l,k > J$ for any arbitraty $\mu$.

Now we apply the identity that you posted but note that this identity can't be used (without worrying about absolute summability) if $q$ is not integral. We will set $a = a_l^{1/n}$ and $q=n$ and $a^q = a_l$, with this arrangement the summation in the identity is finite.

We need to bound the magnitude of the term $(a_l^{(n-1)/n} + a_l^{(n-2)/n} a_k^{1/n} + \ldots + a_k^{(n-1)/n})$. This is easy since the sequence ${a_k}$ must be bounded (why is $a_k$ bounded?). Let $M = \max_k({a_k})$ then the maximum value of this sum is $M^2n$. Set $\mu = \epsilon/M^2n$ and set $I$ equal to the corresponding $J$.

This proves that the new sequence is convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Given $n \in \Bbb N$ we can set $p=q=n$ to obtain:

$a_n - l = (a^{\frac{1}{n}} - l^{\frac{1}{n}})((a^{\frac{1}{n}})^{n-1} + ... + (l^{\frac{1}{n}})^{n-1})$

As $n \rightarrow \infty$, the RHS goes to zero (this is equivalent to $l$ being the limit), so the LHS does as well.If $l \neq0$, argue that the second term on the RHS is not zero for $n$ large, so that the first term actually goes to zero. When $l=0$ should be easier.